# Unit Test for function that will call another function with dynamic values

Tags: java, unit-testing, testing, mockito

I am trying to write a test for a function, `rollDays` and I got a NullPointerException.

I am not exactly sure how should I deal with the test if the method I want to test will call another function `Closed` and will take various dynamic values(date) because of the for loop `for (int numOfDays = Math.abs(days); Closed(date, mar) || numOfDays-- > 0; date = date.plusDays((long) dir))`

The method I want to test is in a class called `CalculateDateService`:
the place where it is called is:
`finalDate = rollDays(3, localDate, DateService.marID);`

The method inside CalculateDateService:

```
LocalDate rollDays(int days, LocalDate date, String mar) {
    int dir = days > 0 ? 1 : -1;
    for (int numOfDays = Math.abs(days); Closed(date, mar) || numOfDays-- > 0; date = date.plusDays((long) dir)){
    }
    return date
}
```

```
Boolean Closed(LocalDate date, String mar) {
    return dateService.Holiday(date, mar) || dateService.Disruption(date, mar) || this.NonSettle(date);
}
```

```
Boolean NonSettle(LocalDate date) {
    LocalDate dayBeforeChristmas = LocalDate.of(dateService.today().getYear(), 12, 24);
    LocalDate dayBeforenewYear = LocalDate.of(dateService.today().getYear(), 12, 31);
    return (date.isEqual(dayBeforeChristmas) || date.isEqual(dayBeforenewYear));
}
```

In the test:

```
@Mock
private DateService dateService;

@InjectMocks
private CalculateDateService tested;

@Test
public void testRollDays() {
        LocalDate initDate = LocalDate.of(2022, 12, 22);
       
        //i suspect I have something wrong below 
        when(tested.Closed(initDate, dateService.marID)).thenReturn(Boolean.FALSE);
        when(dateService.today()).thenReturn(initDate);
        when(tested.NonSettle(initDate)).thenReturn(Boolean.FALSE);
        LocalDate rolledDate = tested.rollDays(4, initDate, DateService.marID);
        LocalDate correctRolledDate = LocalDate.of(2022, 12, 29);
        assertEquals(correctRolledDate, rolledDate);
}
```

The error I got is:

> java.lang.NullPointerException at CalculateDateService.NonSettle 
> at CalculateDateService.Closed
> at CalculateDateServiceTest.testRollDays

Any help will be greatly appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Comment: The code you provided does not compile. Missing return in rollDays.

Comment: I assume that rollDays should add (or subtract) the given number of days but whenever we match some special day related to some holiday, we add one day?

Comment: yes this is true

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Exception is thrown because `tested` is neither a Mock or a Spy.

You might want to try something along the lines of this:

```
    @Test
    void testSpyFalseRoll1201by24(){
        var year = LocalDate.now().getYear();
        var spy = Mockito.spy(new CalculateDateService());
        Mockito.doReturn(false).when(spy).nonSettle(Mockito.any(LocalDate.class));
        var result = spy.rollDays(24, LocalDate.of(year, 12, 1), "");
        Assert.assertEquals(result, LocalDate.of(year, 12, 25));
    }

    @Test
    void testSpyTrueOn1224Roll1201by24(){
        var year = LocalDate.now().getYear();
        var spy = Mockito.spy(new CalculateDateService());
        Mockito.doReturn(false).when(spy).nonSettle(Mockito.any(LocalDate.class));
        Mockito.doReturn(true).when(spy).nonSettle(LocalDate.of(year, 12, 24));
        var result = spy.rollDays(24, LocalDate.of(year, 12, 1), "");
        Assert.assertEquals(result, LocalDate.of(year, 12, 26));
    }
```

What I have done here is stubbing. This works fine in your case but you need to be careful:

> Real spies should be used **carefully and occasionally**, for example when dealing with legacy code.

[Mockito documentation "Spying on real objects"](https://javadoc.io/doc/org.mockito/mockito-core/latest/org/mockito/Mockito.html#spy).

And below this, the documentation says:

> Mockito **does not** delegate calls to the passed real instance, instead it actually creates a copy of it.

Note that I removed DateService, just because it is not part of the problem. Here is my simplified definition of CalculateDateService:

```
public class CalculateDateService {
    LocalDate rollDays(int days, LocalDate date, String mar) {
        int dir = days > 0 ? 1 : -1;
        for(int numOfDays = Math.abs(days); closed(date, mar) || numOfDays-- > 0; date = date.plusDays((long) dir)) {

        }
        return date;
    }

    Boolean closed(LocalDate date, String mar){
        return this.nonSettle(date);
    }

    Boolean nonSettle(LocalDate date)
    {
        int year = LocalDate.now().getYear();
        LocalDate dayBeforeChristmas = LocalDate.of(year, 12, 24);
        LocalDate dayBeforenewYear = LocalDate.of(year, 12, 31);
        return (date.isEqual(dayBeforeChristmas) || date.isEqual(dayBeforenewYear));
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you! If in my case, a date is considered to be close if it's either **nonSettle date, holiday / disruption** (where we need to call DateService's methods, e.g. dateService.holiday & dateService.disruption), then I will also need to mock dateService? Maybe I need to do something like `@Before` to do some initialisation for this dateService mock?

Comment: To explain more, in my case, the `assertEqual` I want to do is when we start with 2021-12-22, we will get 2021-12-29 after rolling 4 days (calling rollDays function). Here rolling 4 days are inclusive of both start & end dates, excluding holidays (weekend, 2021-12-27) and nonSettle day (2021-12-24)

Comment: Don't ask to many questions at once. I recommend that you decide, if this answer answers your **primary** question and later on you could ask a second question independently. My answer is meant to be a starting point. If you start simple and even write your tests first, you get a cleaner design.

Comment: About the second comment: Do not test everything in just one test. Instead of mocking nonSettle you could also test this method first before you even start testing rollDates. After that you can test the closed method and so on.